# Integration about x and y axes to find area

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I have a problem statement that requires me to find area between the curves about x axis and about y axis. But my answers are not matching. Please find below my worked out solution -

[image]

The second-last statement in solving about y-axis is not equating to the answer shown in the last step. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In your second calculation you are finding the area of the right half. That's good, then double. Or else integrate $\sqrt{3-y}-(-\sqrt{3-y})$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! :)

Comment: You are welcome. If I had been doing it, for the first part I would have integrated from $0$ to $2$ and doubled, partly because minus signs can be a problem for me.

Comment: But for the first part, we can't double it right? Because it's not symmetric about the x-axis.

Comment: It is symmetric about the $y$-axis. The area from $x=-2$ to $0$ is the same as the area from $x=0$ to $2$. So we find the area from $0$ to $2$ and double.  But of course your integration from $-2$ to $2$ also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral for calculating the area "under" the $y$-axis involves two components.  Note that for $1\le y\le 3$, the function $x(y)=\pm \sqrt{3-y}$ is double-valued.  Thus,

$$\text{Area} = \int_{1}^{3} \left(\sqrt{3-y}-(-\sqrt{3-y})\right) \,dy=2\int_{1}^{3}  \sqrt{3-y} \,\, dy$$

which will recover the correct answer $\frac{32}{3}$.

Comment: I failed to notice that it is double-valued. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.